# How to hide text in quill editor?

Tags: quill

In html, we can use `display:none, font-size:0, or visibility:hidden` to hide text, is there a similar way in quill editor?

e.g., can set some `op.attributes`, then can hide text

Comment: Do you want to hide all the text or just a portion of it?

Comment: just a portion of it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your answers.
I found a solution for that,
1)Register a attribute:
const HideAttribute = new Parchment.Attributor.Attribute('hidden', 'hidden', config);
Quill.register( HideAttribute, true);
2)For the text need to be hidden, in delta,
op.attributes.hidden = true

Then the text for op.insert will be hidden

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside de Quill container there is a div tag with the "ql-editor" class.
You can target CSS to this class to change the visibility. The div tag is the parent element of all quill content, if you want to hide a portion of text you can target the children to hide. You can use jquery to.

CSS example to hide all the text:

```
.ql-editor{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

CSS example to hide a specified line of the text:

```
.ql-editor p:nth-child(7){
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Remember the differences in "visibility:hidden;" and "display:none;"
[What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and comments. I found a solution for that: